# Counterexample to Cut Property over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

The cut property for real numbers states the following:

> Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and disjoint sets such that $a<b$ for any $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$. Then, there exists a number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\leq c$ for every $x\in A$, and $x\geq c$ for any $x\in B$.

My task is to find a counterexample of the cut property in $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, to find two sets $A,B\subset\mathbb{Q}$ that do not satisfy the cut property.

**Here is my attempt**:

I chose $A=\lbrace \frac{n}{m} | n,m\in\mathbb{Z}; n<m\rbrace\cup (-\infty,0)$ and $B=\lbrace r\in\mathbb{Q} | r>1\rbrace$. 
Not too sure if this combination works.

Comment: The easy choice would be something like $A = \{ x \in \mathbb Q : x^2 < 2\}$, $B = \mathbb Q - A$.

Comment: The presentation of Dedekind cut should begin with the detailed explanation of the fact that rationals don't possess this cut property and then develop reals as Dedekind cuts of rationals so that they do have this property. Your book should have already mentioned examples regarding $\mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: Also note that your set $A$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q} $ as it includes the interval $(-\infty, 0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work; for instance, $1$ is neither is $A$ nor in $B$, and even if it were in one of them, it would be a "cut number".

Hint: consider something like $A = \{ x \in \mathbb Q : x^2 < 2 \text{ or } x < 0\}$, $B = \mathbb Q - A$.

Comment: You should fix the set $A$ as $A=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb {Q}, x<0\text{ or }x^2<2 \} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Of course, thank you.

Comment: Does this satisfy $a<b$ for all $b\in B$? Nevermind, saw the edit.

Comment: @高田航 Yes. Elements in $B$ are rational numbers that are greater than $\sqrt 2$.